# Sending an array of integers with MPI_Send, a subtle confusion

Tags: c, count, mpi

I am new to MPI. Apologies if it is a stupid question. I wonder whether the parameter `count` in `MPI_Send()` means that it will send an array (size `count`) of the given datatype in one go or that it will spits the given datatype one at a time and do so `count` times.

Comment: `count` elements with the given datatype are sent in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

Logically, **one message** is sent by a call to `MPI_Send()`.

How this maps to the actual network or local communication is up to the implementation. You may safely assume that it is efficient, but it should not matter to your application how many streams, packets, fragments, flits or whatever are involved in transferring the message.